# Как пишется и произносится дата — с такого-то по такой-то год/года/годы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, даты

Как произносится *с 1869 по 1900 года*?

Answer (score 2):

> Как произносится с 1869 по 1900 года?

Произносится и пишется:

с тысяча восемьсот шестьдесят девятого по тысяча девятисотый год (с 1869 по 1900 год).

---

**[Вопрос № 235844](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=235844%09%20)**

> Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйстата, как правильно: с 2004 по 2007
>   годы/год? Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Правильно: *с 2004 по 2007 год*.

**[Вопрос № 290422](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=235844%09%20)**

> Доброго времени суток, уважаемые сотрудники Грамоты.ру. Скажите,
>   пожалуйста, как правильно писать: с 1994 по 2012 год или годы? Заранее
>   благодарна.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Верно: *с 1994 по 2012 год* (это не однородные члены).

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае предлог "**по**" относится только к *одному* названному году (этим указывается граница интервала), поэтому "год", например:

> Это продолжалось с 1869 (-го) по 1900 (-й) **год**.

Один год подразумевается даже в таком случае:

> Годы с 1869 (-го) по 1900 (-й) [**год**] были тяжелыми.

С другими предлогами возможно общее указание на весь временной интервал:

> На 1869 (-й) — 1900 (-й) год**ы** планировалась реформа.
>
> В 1869 (-м) — 1900 (-м) год**ах** население увеличивалось.

Answer (score 1):

Для записи этих дат используются [составные порядковые числительные](http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/ebbc76cf-46b6-4d51-ad92-d9a84db35cfa/[I-RUS_06-05]_[TE_16-SU]/[I-RUS_06-05]_[TE_16-SU].html), которые обозначают порядок предметов при счёте.
Порядковые числительные согласуются с существительными в числе, роде и падеже, как прилагательные (**год** — м. р., ед. ч.). При склонении у них изменяется только последняя часть: две тысячи *девятнадцатый год* — в две тысячи *девятнадцатом году.*

**С** (какого? Р. п.) **тысяча восемьсот шестьдесят *девятого*** [года] **по** (какой? В. п.) **тысяча *девятисотый год*** (см. [**1900**](https://numeralonline.ru/1900)).

Стоит отметить, что порядковое числительное *девятисотый* само по себе является сложным.

Answer (score 1):

С тысяча восемьсот шестьдесят девятого по тысяча девятисотый год. Здесь к существительному "год" относится только второе числительное,  поэтому род — единственный.  Бывают такие примеры: с девяностых по нулевые года.  Здесь числительные обозначают не конкретные порядковые номера годов, а целые периоды, в которых год не один, а несколько.